# What is the benefit of parent and child Entity in GAE?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How will I know if the entity I am creating should be a child entity or not?

```
DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Entity E = new Entity("Person",52);
E.setProperty("FirstName","Jack");
E.setProperty("LastName","Patrick");
E.setProperty("Gender","Male");
ds.put(E)
```

Now I have an entity called `User`, what is the benefit I get if I create `User` as a child of `Person`?

Comment: do you need to find all users 'owned' by person?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is explained well in the existing documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ancestor-queries are strongly consistent (while global queries, not specifying ancestors, are only "eventually consistent").  Moreover, **transactions** are allowed only among "entity groups", meaning one or more entities which have an ancestor in common.

Thus, you should specify a parent for an entity if, and only if, you intend to ever use it in a transaction, or need to be able to query for it in a strongly consistent way.  If neither need applies, then avoiding the parent saves you time and resources.